# Torch Network load does not processed properly

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to make a network using 3x64x64 image at pytorch environment, and it seems that I succeeded in training my network and save it. The network looks like :

```
class LC_small(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,c_in,c_out = 256):
    super(LC_small,self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = conv(c_in,64,k=3,stride=1,pad=1)
        self.conv2 = conv(64, 128, k=3, stride=2, pad=1)
        self.conv3 = conv(128, 128, k=3, stride=1, pad=1)
        self.conv4 = conv(128, 128, k=3, stride=2, pad=1)
        self.conv5 = conv(128, 128, k=3, stride=1, pad=1)
        self.conv6 = conv(128, 256, k=3, stride=2, pad=1)
        self.conv7 = conv(256, 256, k=3, stride=1, pad=1)# int(h/8 x w/8 x 256)
        self.flat = dense(int(w_rsz/8)*int(h_rsz/8)*256,256)
        self.dense1 = dense(256,128,False)
        self.dense2 = dense(128,3,False)
    def forward(self, input):
        out = self.conv1(input)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.conv3(out)
        out = self.conv4(out)
        out = self.conv5(out)
        out = self.conv6(out)
        out = self.conv7(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0),-1)
        out = self.flat(out)
        out = self.dense1(out)
        out = self.dense2(out)
         # print(out.shape)
        normal = torch.nn.functional.normalize(out, 2, 1)

        return normal
```

And I saved my model while Training :

```
for epoch in range(10):
#  continue    # 현재 Training 됐다고 가정하고
    total_loss = 0
    route_param = open(route_diffuse+'/netparam.txt','w')
    for param in lcnet.state_dict():
    route_param.write(str(param)+'\t'+str(lcnet.state_dict()[param].size())+'\n')
    for i,data in enumerate(load_LC,0):
    input, gtval = data[0].to(dev),data[1].to(dev)
    opt.zero_grad()

    output = lcnet(input)
    loss = crit(output,gtval)
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
    total_loss +=loss.item()
    if i%10 == 9:
         print(epoch,i,total_loss/10)
         torch.save(lcnet,route_save)
         total_loss = 0
```

However, by the time I try to load the network I made I saw a error message as following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "E:/DLPrj/venv/torch_practice.py", line 324, in <module>

ipl,npl = getseqi_np(sq_t,lcnet)   #  data : 8 x 6 x w x h 

File "E:/DLPrj/venv/torch_practice.py", line 133, in getseqi_np

l1 = net_lc(torch.from_numpy(i1r))

File "E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__

result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

File "E:/DLPrj/venv/torch_practice.py", line 216, in forward

out = self.conv1(input)

File "E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__

result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

File "E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 92, in forward

input = module(input)

File "E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__

result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

File "E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 345, in forward

return self.conv2d_forward(input, self.weight)

File "E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 342, in conv2d_forward

self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)

RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 64 3 3 3, but got 3-dimensional input of size [64, 64, 3] instead
```

After this error pycharm freezes and I cannot re-run this code until I restart the pycharm.

When I train my network, I also get some warning messages :

```
E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:292: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type LC_small. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.

 "type " + obj.__name__ + ". It won't be checked "

E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:292: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type Sequential. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.

 "type " + obj.__name__ + ". It won't be checked "

E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:292: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type Conv2d. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.

 "type " + obj.__name__ + ". It won't be checked "

E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:292: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type BatchNorm2d. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.

 "type " + obj.__name__ + ". It won't be checked "

E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:292: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type LeakyReLU. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.

 "type " + obj.__name__ + ". It won't be checked "

E:\DLPrj\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:292: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type Linear. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.

 "type " + obj.__name__ + ". It won't be checked "
```

I cannot understand why the input size the network takes suddenly changes, or why it saved my network wrong. Please check my problem and thank you very much.

Comment: You aren't showing the code for how you saved the model so we can't really help you debug this issue.

Comment: Oh sorry. I added my save code in the middle .

Answer (score 0):

So your first error message is because torch.from_numpy(i1r) has the wrong shape.  You need to do

```
np.expand_dims(i1r.transpose(2,0,1), axis=0)
```

Then it'll get processed correctly.  This is because it expects a batch dimension and you aren't providing one along with the channels being in the first  dimension not the last.

As for your second error message it's probably because you incorrectly defined conv, and dense so it messes up when saving the model.